# Using createItem remote API with CloudBees folder plugin to create nested jobs or subdirectories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

I am attempting to create nested directories and jobs mirroring the structure of my SVN repository using the CloudBees Folder plugin and Jenkins remote API.

For a subdirectory (assume I've copied the config.xml to my CWD):

```
wget --no-proxy --auth-no-challenge --http-user=username --ask-password --header="Content-Type: application/xml" --post-file="dconfig.xml" 'http://ci.mycompany.com/jenkins/createItem?name=foo'
```

works.  When the command completes, I have a newly created "foo" folder in the top level of my dashboard.  However when I try:

```
wget --no-proxy --auth-no-challenge --http-user=username --ask-password --header="Content-Type: application/xml" --post-file="dconfig.xml" 'http://ci.mycompany.com/jenkins/createItem?name=foo/bar'
```

I get a "ERROR 400: Bad Request".  I've also tried substituting "name=/foo/bar", "name=%2Ffoo%2Fbar", and "name=foo%2Fbar", all with the same results.

Likewise, I get a similar result when using the createItem/from/mode/name API to copy internal folders:

```
wget --no-proxy --auth-no-challenge --http-user=username --ask-password --header="Content-Type: application/xml" --post-file="dconfig.xml" 'http://ci.mycompany.com/jenkins/createItem?name=foo/bar&mode=copy&from=foo'
```

I find this very unusual since - through the web interface - I can easily move, copy, and create nested directories and jobs.

I am using Jenkins 1.569 with the CloudBees Folders 4.7 plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`name` may only be a simple name. The endpoint you are looking for is on the folder, not at root level. Thus

```
wget --no-proxy --auth-no-challenge --http-user=username --ask-password --header="Content-Type: application/xml" --post-file="dconfig.xml" 'http://ci.mycompany.com/jenkins/job/foo/createItem?name=bar'
```